# Set DatetimeField to null in ASP.NET SQL server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have the following code to insert data into table.Table has field BlockTime which is of type DateTime. I want to initialize BlockTime to null. This is the part of my code where i want to initialize it to null.

```
var tracktable = new TrackTable
{
IPAddress = ipadd,
LastLoginResult = "Failed",
LastLoginTime = DateTime.Now,
LoginAttemptStreak = 1,
BlockTime = null // Set BlockTime to null
};
model.InsertTrack(tracktable);
```

The above method gives error.
How can i initialize the variable to null. I googled and found similar questions.  I copy pasted those solutions and none of them worked. How can i set above BlockTime to null initially. Do i have to do anything in sql server before editing in c#.

Comment: `"The above method gives error."` - Reading the error message is always a good first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use DBNull.Value and make sure your property is nullable.

```
var tracktable = new TrackTable
{
IPAddress = ipadd,
LastLoginResult = "Failed",
LastLoginTime = DateTime.Now,
LoginAttemptStreak = 1,
BlockTime = DBNull.Value
};
model.InsertTrack(tracktable);
```

Comment: I changed my code. It shows "cannot resolve name DB" error.

Comment: Look at my code again. Use DBNull.Value and let me know if it worked or not

Comment: Sorry. I corrected the typo. Now it shows "Cant implicitly convert type System.DBNull to System.Datetime".

Comment: You need to make BlockTime nullable . It is in other answers. Just use a question mark as you see in other answers

Answer (score 0):

BlockTime must be a nullable datetime

> public DateTime? BlockTime {get; set;}

or

> public Nullable BlockTime {get; set;}

Comment: Should i place this inside struct or outside?

Comment: wherever  TrackTable is definied. is it a class or struct?